# Windows 10 Mount SMB Share without Credentials

Tags: windows, mount, samba, smb

I want to mount a share on Windows 10 Home PC. However, when I try to mount it, it says that I dont have permission to access the share. So I setup a VM (Ubuntu 20.04) and tried to mount it there. At first it also didnt work (mount error(2): No such file or directory). I found out that I had to put `sec=none` in order to connect to the share:

`sudo mount.cifs //server/share /Data/path -o sec=none`

Now my question is, how can I mount it on my Windows System with the sec=none settings? 
What I tried:

- activating Optional Features: SMB 1.0/CIFS Filesharing Support  - Client
- leaving username/password blank
- / or \ as username, password blank
- username: guest etc..

**Edit:**

- **After a few hours changing registry and group policy, I found a
  solution that works for me. Just use that command in the command
  prompt: 
  `net use x: \\server\share /user:""  ""`**